# Perfmon data collector set not putting data in SQL

Tags: sql-server, performancecounter, perfmon

I have created a perfmon data collector set to store perf counter data in SQL server. I used the instructions [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/08/27/how-to-store-performance-monitor-data-into-sql-server-using-reliability-and-performance-monitor.aspx).  I did all the steps, but after starting the Data Collector Set it doesn't seem like the data is being put anywhere.  I have it setup to use a localhost System DSN but the database remains empty.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Found it.  It looks like the DSN didn't have a default database setup, so the new tables were all created in `master`.